# Stop NestJs server process from client

Tags: next.js, nestjs

I have a nextJs web application with a nestJS backend, from the webapp I can call the server and it calls a gRPC process and returns information back to the client. How do I terminate this process when it's still running? Simply closing the browser window or using `new AbortController()` only kills the API call between server and client but does not kill the server process that is still fetching data from gRPC.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to shut down your nestJS application use

```
process.exit()
```

which terminates the running node process.